# can someone explain this function

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain to me how this function works?

```
var randomize = function(length){
  var text = "";
  var possible = "123abc";

  for (var i = 0 ; i < length; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length))

  return text;
}

console.log(randomize(6));
```

I'm trying to understand it but some lines don't make sense.

Comment: can you specify the question? which lines doesn't make sense?

Comment: *"I'm trying to understand it but some lines don't make sense."* What lines? What has your research turned up? If you don't already know about it, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) is an excellent reference source for JavaScript.

Comment: This one : 

text += possible.charAt
why does it have to be +=

Comment: @CristianCandidatu `variable += value` is a shorthand for `variable = variable + value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`possible` - list of characters to choose from

`Math.random()` returns a float number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)

`Math.random()*possible.length` makes it a float number between 0 and `possible.length`

`Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length)` makes it an integer between 0 (inclusive) and `possible.length` (exclusive)

`possible.charAt(position_here)` takes a character at position `position_here` from the string `possible` (0-indexed)

`text += something_here` is the same as `text = text + something_here`. Append another string (in this case: character) to already existing value of text.